# How do I diagnose freezer forming frost around door?

Tags: freezer, frost

My freezer is repeatedly developing frost by the top door seal. I’ve done the dollar test on the top seal, but it doesn’t feel that loose! The problem is I’m not sure how strong it’s supposed to be. The fridge is only a couple of years old. Anything else I can/should do to diagnose it? Or should I just order a new seal? Anything placed in the top door compartment develops frost on top, which my intuition would say means it’s coming in contact with warm air, but I’m not sure.

[image]

EDIT: I didn’t even think to look at the hinge. It looks like the right side of the freezer door is almost a centimeter higher than the left side, and it slants downward. Is that normal?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pictures of the hinge hardware?

Comment: Bad door seals? Door not closing fully?

Comment: You could clean the seal and repeat the dollar test

Comment: "The fridge is only a couple of years old" Is it still under warranty? If so, call the manufacturer for a warranty claim.

Comment: It's probably weather-related if you're in summer right now, so it will go away on it's own. Add vaseline to the rubber to make a tighter seal meanwhile if it's a concern.

Comment: Don't you *want* the door to shut when open?  Does your unit not have adjustable feet?

Comment: It does have adjustable feet ‍♂️ I didn't know that was a thing! I'm going to mark this as answered, thanks everyone for teaching me about refrigerators. Will try Vaseline as a temporary solution and futz around with the leveling and door hinges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oddest is that it seems to be evenly not sealed along the whole length.

Usually over time, the end nearest the hinge will compress more than the open face, causing the seal to weaken farthest from the hinge as it gets used to being wedge-shaped over time.
The quick fix for that is to rotate the seal 180° [like a picture frame upside down] & refit. This is usually very easy to do, it will just clip in. Remove the plastic door insert first. That will give you another decade or so.

For it to be so far out for its entire length, though, makes me think the top hinge is offset too far outwards; either there's some adjustment in the structure which needs tightening back up, or the hinge is worn & needs replacing.

A late thought - perhaps it's meant to meet seal to metal, not half & half on the plastic. That could mean the bottom hinge has an adjuster for height, which has moved over time. Last time I had to re-jig mine, I discovered the lower hinge had actually slightly bent downwards over the years, but there was a double nut-lock which could be used to adjust the overall height.
You could try just lifting the door to see if there's any play in it & also if it will lift far enough to match seal>metal without the insert hitting the edge.

Another late thought - I wonder if the fridge insert, rather than the door insert, has moved forwards, holding the seal off the metal part a little, or even if the two inserts are hitting each other as the door closes.
Trying to see that happen will be like trying to spot the light go off… maybe something squishy, easily transferable on one edge, close, open, see if it's transferred to the other insert at all. All I can think of is lipstick, though I'm not sure how popular you'd be a) ruining the tube & b) getting pink everywhere inside the fridge ;)  Maybe Vaseline instead.

Comment: Re: flipping the seal 180°: Wouldn't this then leave the compressed-over-time end, formerly by the hinge, now being a bit short at the handle side, allowing loads of air to pass by? If the seal's been squished more at the hinge, I'd think it would stay that way when rotated. I was about to add this to my to-do list when that thought hit, so I'd love some feedback to know if you've actually done this.

Comment: @FreeMan - No. You'd think it might but I did this on my 20-year-old fridge a few years back - the strip was getting tatty too where people dig their fingers into it rather than pull the handle. Took 30 mins, while I had it apart I gave the door a good steam clean too. Good as new. Tatty bit is now out of sight by the hinge. No leaks, & it all just fits the gap perfectly. Even slightly triangular the face is still perfectly flat, so it just adapted. Wanted to avoid the ridiculous price of a new seal if I could. Well worth the effort.

Comment: On the to-do list it goes! 30-year-old fridge is leaking a bit of air from the fridge & freezer compartments. Haven't looked yet, but replacement bits are probably hard to source these days, so this will be nice. Need a replacement, but we have a small kitchen and need a small fridge, not one of the new behemoths they sell now...

Comment: @FreeMan - Yeah. I hope mine outlasts me, because it took 6 of us to get it in place, a real Harry Houdini job; so I will do almost anything to avoid ever having to try get it out again. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDSIV.jpg [Yeah, I could have tidied up first, just call me messy ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin: Using fingers to spread the seal may be necessary if the force required on the handle to break the vacuum would exceed the friction force on the floor.

Comment: Thanks! I added some photos of the hinge and how the door is sitting, but again I don’t know what normal looks like. I’m now wondering if both the fridge door and freezer are having the same issue, which would explain some things about the fridge as well. I will try and see if I can find a manual or something for the fridge to see if there’s something to compare it to

Comment: So I feel like my question has morphed from the original question to: why does my fridge have such a pronounced lean? If you think I should, I’m happy to accept this as the right answer (since it was very helpful in understanding how to think about the problem) and I’ll ask an entirely new question.